# Expected value of a piecewise function that depends on the value of another random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value

How do I calculate the expected value of the following random variable (Y). Suppose that a is a > 0.

$Y = \begin{cases}
       a , \: \:X \ge a\\
       0 , \: \:X < a\\
      \end{cases}$

In my textbook it is written that $E(Y) = a\:P(X \ge a)$ but I do not know how they calculated this.

Y's value seem to depend on what the outcome of the random variable X is. So is it fair to assume that Y is a conditional random variable?

Comment: I don't know what a conditional random variable is, but from the Definition it does follow that $X,Y$ are not independent. In any case, note that $Y$ is discrete and maybe you can take it from there.

Comment: This is used in a proof of Markov's inequality if $X$ is a non-negative random variable: clearly $Y \le X$ so $\mathbb E[Y]\le \mathbb E[X]$ assuming the latter exists, and since $\mathbb E[Y] = 0 \times \mathbb P(X \lt a) + a\times  \mathbb P(X \ge a)$ you get  $a\mathbb P(X \ge a) \le \mathbb E[X] $ and thus $\mathbb P(X \ge a) \le \frac1a \mathbb E[X]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y=a1_{\{X\ge a\}}$ so $E[Y]=E[a1_{\{X\ge a\}}]=aE[1_{\{X\ge a\}}]=a P(X\ge a)$.

I recall that for a (measurable) set $B$, $1_{\{X\in B\}}$ is the random variable which is equal to $1$ if $X\in B$, and $0$ else. With the definition of expected value we have
$$
E[1_{\{X\in B\}}] = 1\times P(X\in B) + 0\times P(X\notin B)=P(X\in B).
$$

Just apply the latter with $B=[a,+\infty)$.

Comment: What does $Y=a1_{\{X\ge a\}}$ mean? Sorry I dont understand the notation properly

Comment: @DanielDeWet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function